# arduino beginner documentation help

Tags: arduino-mega, shields, arduino-yun

I plan to buy these 2 products to begin to play with arduino to learn.

1. [Board with LCD touch](http://www.banggood.com/UNO-R3-ATmega328P-Board-2_4-Inch-TFT-LCD-Screen-Module-For-Arduino-p-945755.html)
2. [Yun board expansion](http://www.banggood.com/Iduino-Yun-Shield-Expansion-Module-Board-Compatible-Arduino-p-979882.html)

I have a mega 2560 which i bought with a starter kit and i love to play with. I have not played with the shield yet. I understand some shields can be used together, some not. and some with modification on the board and in the code.

I can't find pins specification for the touch screen and the support on the website doesn't respond.

If some one can help me find specifications for the touch screen, or help me choose some shields that will allow me to use a USB host, wifi, and a touchscreen it will be nice.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [link you posted](http://m.banggood.com/UNO-R3-ATmega328P-Board-2_4-Inch-TFT-LCD-Screen-Module-For-Arduino-p-945755.html) describes a TFT LCD Touch screen unit with the SPFD5408 controller, referenced in [this Instructable](http://m.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-24-inch-TFT-LCD-SPFD5408-with-Arduino-U/) for use with the Mega. You might start there and migrate to the Yun once you get the screen working.